# Maintaing order of dictionary when converting list to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
List = [('The', 'DT'), ('study', 'NN'), ('guide', 'NN'), ('does', 'VBZ'), ('not', 'RB'), ('discuss', 'VB'), ('much', 'JJ'), ('of', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('basics', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), ('ethics.', 'NN')]
```

I convert it to a dictionary using

```
dic=collections.OrderedDict()
dic=dict(List)
```

when i print the dictionary the order isn't maintained in the way it is in the list.

I tried using OrderedDict() but still the order isn't maintained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just convert the list *directly* to an `OrderedDict`:

```
dic = collections.OrderedDict(List)
```

Dictionaries inherently are *unordered*. If you want to have some semblance of order, you *need* to use an `OrderedDict`. Converting back to a dictionary basically defeats the point.

Note that an `OrderedDict` has virtually the same interface as a regular dictionary, and you lose nothing in using an `OrderedDict` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
dic=collections.OrderedDict()
dic=dict(List)
```

on the second line, you erase the `OrderedDict` and replace it with a `dict`.

You should do `collections.OrderedDict(List)`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `dic = dict(List)`, you are creating a normal (arbitrarily ordered) dictionary. Just call `dic = collections.OrderedDict(List)`